# JSON schema validation for JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have list of objects that i have converted to JSONArray, i want to validate it against a JSON schema (Schema object) and collect the error if any for each object in the list.
(i dont want to use loop)

Could someone tell me how can i do it in java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String jsonData = "[{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30},{\"name\":\"Jane\",\"age\":25},{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":null}]";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);

        // JSON schema
        String schemaJson = "{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"age\":{\"type\":\"number\"}}}}";
        JsonSchemaFactory schemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance();
        JsonSchema schema = schemaFactory.getSchema(schemaJson);

        // Validate JSON data against the schema
        Map<Integer, List<ValidationMessage>> validationErrors = jsonNode.stream()
                .flatMap(JsonNode::elements)
                .map(node -> schema.validate(node))
                .filter(vr -> !vr.isSuccess())
                .flatMap(vr -> vr.getMessages().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ValidationMessage::getNode, Collectors.toList()));

        // Print validation errors
        validationErrors.forEach((index, errors) -> {
            System.out.println("Errors for object at index " + index + ":");
            errors.forEach(error -> System.out.println("  " + error.getMessage()));
        });
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to use loop for this, can we do it through ArraySchema